# Stop loop in class from another class

Tags: c#, .net, loops

So I have two event handlers button1_Click() and button2_Click()

In button1_Click() I have something running like this:

```
toGet = textbox1.Text;
got = 0;

while (got <= toGet)
{
  //DoStuff
}
```

But button2_Click is supposed to be a stop button, and stop button1 early.
How do I go about this?
Thanks for the help. I saw [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338894/stop-a-loop-inside-a-method-in-c) here about it, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Are you running in a single thread, as mentioned in the accepted answer to the question you linked to?

Comment: Winforms? WebForms? WPF?

Comment: Please tell what happened. "couldn't get it to work" doesn't help much

Answer (score 1):

**Windows.Forms answer**

The least sophisticated method is this:

```
private bool m_stop;
private void button1_Click (object s, EventArgs ea)
{
   try
   {
   //  Don't forget to disable all controls except the ones you want a user to be able to click while your method executes.

      toGet = textbox1.Text;
      got = 0;

      while (got <= toGet)
      {
        Application.DoEvents (); 
        // DoEvents lets other events fire.  When they are done, resume.
        if (m_stop)
           break;
        //DoStuff
      }

   finally
   {
      //  Enable the controls you disabled before.
   }
}

private void button2_Click (object s, EventArgs ea)
{
   m_stop = true;
}
```

It has the distinct advantage of letting you execute button1_Click on the UI thread, still lets the UI respond to your stop button.

It has a disadvantage that you must protect against reentrancy.  What happens if they click your button1 while button1_click is already executing!?!?

**Edit:**  Another way I have used is to use a Timer instead of a loop.  Then, the stop method just stops the timer.

Comment: When I do this I get name "m_stop" doesn't exist in this context
in button1

Comment: Add this field to your class: `private bool m_stop;`

Comment: +1 for timer. But consider that folowing your "single thread rule" you can use only System.Windows.Forms.Timer. If this is winforms( not really clear yet)

Comment: `Application.DoEvent()` is really bad advice and introduce problems more than it really solves..

Comment: Ahh I figured it out. Just made stop a global variable

Comment: @Jalal we already in wired situation, so Application.DoEvents hardly can make things worse :)

Comment: @Jalal, I think reentrancy is easier to explain than multithreading.  With multithreading, you have to worry about which thread is "touching" the UI controls.  I am fine with threading, but I can remember back to when I first started programming and there's no way a multithreading answer would be easier to understand than DoEvents.

Comment: I agree it is `easier to explain than multithreading` but I think that the problem it introduce should be avoided from the beginning.. so is worth to learn multithreading instead of it, his scenario is more like a search method "you can think of the scenario as a search  method that searches for files or folders and when click stop the search", so it is fit to be multithreading...

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understood, correct me if I'm wrong, you're on single thread.
Wired, but you can check for single boolean value  inside the your While loop, just as post suggested.

May be to make life easier (may be this is what "couldn't get it to work" means) is inside loop call

1) Windows Forms: `Application.DoEvents()`

2) WPF (little bit more tricky) :  [DoEvents in WPF](http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2007/08/how-to-doevents-in-wpf.html)

This to make breathe system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the process inside the `button1` in new thread, and when you press the `button2` flag a local variable to false to stop the loop. like:

```
using System.Threading;

private volatile bool _requestStop = false;
private readonly object _oneExecuteLocker = new object();    


private void OnButton1Click(ojbect sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_oneExecuteLocker))
        {//if we are here that is means the code is not already running..
            try
            {
                while (!_requestStop)
                {
                    //DoStuff
                } 
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_oneExecuteLocker);
            }
        }
    }){ IsBackground = true }.Start();
}

private void OnButton2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _requestStop = true;
}
```

Notes:

- When ever you want to update a UI control inside the newly created thread you should use `contorl.Invoke(/*the code get/set or call method in the UI*/)`.
- The `Monitro.Enter` is just to be sure that your code will not executed multiple time per click if it already running.